# How to change the size of the characters inside a UIPicker

Tags: iphone, ios, uipicker, text-size

I am trying to center and change the size of the text inside my UIPicker but am not sure how... I think it might happen in one of these methods, most likely the first...

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pv titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x",row ] uppercaseString]; //Sets picker options as an Uppercase Hex value
}


#pragma mark UIPickerViewDataSource methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView*)pv
{
    return 5; //5 columns in the picker
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pv numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 16;
}
```

Dose anyone one know how this can be done? I have looked around but the documentation is fairly thin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Johns,

As in Table Views, you can't change the font attributes of the default title that you usually set in the titleForRow delegate method, instead you have to use the following method:

```
- (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Here you can create an UIView with a custom UILabel and set the Label's font size, color and other attributes.

This method is described in [Apple's UIPickerView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

Hope this help you!

Comment: wow... thats a real letdown.. you would think apple would cover this sort of thing in that titleForRow delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Now with iOS 6 you can use NSAttributedStrings to customize the title text (though I don't think this lets you easily center the text).

A new UIPickerViewDelegate method lets you return an attributed string instead of a plain vanilla string:

(NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

The NSAttributedString UIKit additions page has a list of all the character attributes you can control:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688